# pass few properties to a custom action

Tags: properties, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

What is a standart way of passing properties to a custom action without parsing them? I mean if I write "X1=X1value X2=X2value", then in my custom action X1 will be equal to "X1value X2=X2value", and X2 won't exist as a separate property. So what is the properties string format?

Comment: What language is your CustomAction in?  VBScript, JScript, InstallScript, C/C++ ( using WiX wcautil.lib/dutil.lib? ), C# ( Installer Class or DTF )?

Comment: my CustomAction uses WiX custom action template and is written in C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know that there is a "standard" for serializing and serializng CustomActionData.  There are a couple libraries out there though.  If you happen to be using C# DTF custom actions there is a CustomActionData class that can serialize and deserialize the property collection for you.   Otherwise you pretty much come up with your own pattern like:

/PROPERTYA=VALUEA /PROPERTYB=VALUEB

or

PROPERTYA=VALUEA;PROPERTYB=VALUEB

Or even an XML fragment like

```
<Properties>
 <Property Id="PROPERTYA">VALUEA</Property>
 <Property Id="PROPERTYB">VALUEB</Property>
</Properties>
```

The point is to serialize and deserialize so that it can be available to your deferred CA.

Comment: yes, I use DTF CustomActionData class. In what format the strings should be written for CustomActionData to deserialize the values successfully?

Comment: Figured out that I can use ; as property separators and then WiX will deserialize them ok .

Comment: A type 51 Set Property custom action will work, but if your requirements get more complicated ( say you are querying a custom table, evaluating component action states and then generating a command set )  you can also use another DTF custom action to create the CustomActionData class then serialize it out to the string.